# Update another component based on a change in the selectonemenu value

Tags: ajax, jsf-1.2, selectonemenu

We are using JSF 1.2 for our project. Requirement is to update another selectonemenu options based on a value change in the current selectonemenu.

Based on select1 option, select2 needs to be updated.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="select1" value="#{subscription.subscriptions}" onchange="javascriptMethod()">
    <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="News" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Sports" itemValue="2" />        
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="panel2">
 <h:selectOneMenu id="select2" value="#{subscription.subscriptions2}">
    <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="News" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Sports" itemValue="2" />        
</h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax support like this

```
  <h:selectOneMenu id="select1" value="#{subscription.subscriptions}"   >
    <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="News" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Sports" itemValue="2" />  


 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Jsf 1.2 doesn't have ajax support the only thing you can do is full page reload which happens on a command button.

I presumed you are using richfaces as a third party for ajax and rich ui components. 
Hope this helps.

If you are using primefaces then you can replace  tag with  like this

```
<p:ajax event="onchange" update="select2" action="if you want to anything in   
                                                                      backend"/>
```

If you want to do by javascript then have a hidden h:commandButton and put code in your
javascriptMethod() method like this

```
     document.getElementById("myHiddenButtonId").click();
```